# Tkinter- creating 5x5 matrix of circles with spaces in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
for row in range(0,5):
  for col in range(0,5):
    c.create_oval(50*col, 50*row, 50*(col+1), 50*(row+1))
```

I'm attempting to create a 5x5 matrix of circles (on a window that's 250x250). I want the circles to have diameters of 40 with a space of 10 in between them. My code right now creates circles with diameters of 50 with no spaces in between. I can't seem to figure out how to space them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `create_oval accepts` `x0,y0,x1,y1` as parameters. Thus, if you want your circles to have diameters of 40, the difference between `x0` and `x1`, and `y0` and `y1`, should be 40. You can achieve this with:

```
c.create_oval(50*col, 50*row, (50*(col+1)) - 10, (50*(row+1))) - 10)
```

This just subtracts 10 from `x1` and `y1`, which shortens the diameter, which also creates the space you want. It's also equivalent to:

```
 c.create_oval(50*col, 50*row, (50*col) + 40, 50*(row) + 40)
```

Answer (score -1):

for row and column wise both, if from the second circle, it starts from 10+previous circle-ends, then it gets spaced out

```
b = 0
for row in range(0,5):
    a = 0;
    for col in range(0,5):
        canvas.create_oval(40*col+a, 40*row+b, 40*(col+1)+a, 40*
       (row+1)+b)
        a = a + 10
    b = b + 10
```

Comment: Make sure you add a bit of explanation to your answer so future visitors have an easier time understanding it.